# Sending data consecutively to two different IPs with socket.socket: is it standard behaviour that the NAT keeps the same port?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, nat, hole-punching

From my home computer behind a standard home router / NAT, I am opening a single `socket`, and sending data to two different servers (with different public IP):

```
import socket, time
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
for addr in ['203.0.113.2', '198.51.100.77']:
    soc.sendto(b'', (addr, 4000))
    data, _ = soc.recvfrom(6)
    print(data)
    time.sleep(2)
```

On the first server listening on port 4000, I notice that 4000 has been translated by the NAT to port 57358.

On the second server listening on port 4000, I notice that 4000 **has also been translated to port 57358**.

Is it standard documented behaviour that when

- opening a socket
- sending data to a first server,
- NAT router translating the port 4000 to 57358

then, **when sending data to another IP with the same socket, the NAT will translate the port 4000 *to the same port*?** (57358 in my example)

or is it just luck?

---

Note: I've tested this both from a computer connected to a home ISP router and from a computer connected to my phone tethering via WiFi, in both cases, I get the same behaviour.

Comment: The implementation of NAPT is up to the vendor of the NAPT device. One device may do it that way, and another device do it differently.

Comment: This is probably the answer @RonMaupin (could you post it?). I thought that maybe using a *single socket* will keep some connection alive so that when switching to another destination IP, the NAT will know it should give the same NAT-translated port.

Comment: OK. I did that.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be various [methods of translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation) such as Symmetric NAT:

[image],

full-cone NAT, post-restricted cone NAT, etc. and each of them might lead to different behaviours (?).

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of NAPT is up to the vendor of the NAPT device. One device may do it that way, and another device do it differently.